# mysql select WHERE string is in array - string contain spaces

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, select

I use this:

```
$cat_manuals = array(
                        "Drama",
                        "SF",
                        "Crime",
                        "Comedy",
                        "Black Humor"
                        );
        $cat_manuals = '"' . implode('","', $cat_manuals) . '"';
$query120 = "SELECT title FROM books WHERE genre IN ($cat_manuals)"
```

The issue is with elements in array which contain spaces, the query returns junk when searchig for "Black Humor". If I rename it it "BlackHumor" it work. How do I escape the spaces ? In query or in array ?

Comment: If you have a hardcoded array of categories/genres, I would think you need to properly enforce the naming methodology across the application and the database or provide a mapping between the application values and the database values.  Why is the category simply not called "Black Humor" in the database?

Comment: As an additional note, you also might consider normalizing your database to have a table for genres that you reference from books. Not doing this will made it hard for you to scale the number of genres you use.

Comment: Hi,
Unfortunately I cannot modify the table. The categories are already there and hard coded into the system, changing them would mean a lot of work. I only use this for a quick extra tool to list them so I thought there is a way to avoid using many "OR" statements in the mysql query.

Oh, the above query is just an analogy, I actually have car models as categories in my database, thousands of them.

Comment: This still is a really trivial problem if you just need to remove spaces from these strings.  Can you show what you have tried to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi,
I eventually went another way and achived what I wanted by using an extra column that those categories had.
Basically I wanted to list only some categories from the database, the only problem was that there was no criteria to catch them on, other than manually specify them in a SELECT statement so I tried using a small array with them listed manually. But now I figured I could just add to them a small "flag" in a separate column and select them using that flag. It is easier :).

Thank you very much !